# DataSet Editor is missing from the "Open With" dialog in VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, dataset-designer

I'm using Visual Studio 2005.  I normally use the *DataSet Editor* to design datasets.  However, this option is no longer available in the *Open With* dialog.  Visual Studio now defaults to designing datasets with the *XML Schema Editor*.

How can I get the *DataSet Editor* restored as an available option when designing datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the DataSet Editor back is to launch the Visual Studio Command Prompt and run: devenv /Setup

This will cause Visual Studio to merge the resource meta data that is used to populate the "Open With..." menu option, among other things.

Answer (score -1):

Yes nice , this is the thing that worked , I first tried this command that I rememebred to reset :

devenv.exe/resetsettings

It opened VS2005 configured it (looked like) but then the desginser for the dataset were still missing .

So instead of resetting use the devenv/Setup command , as it resolved my problem .

Regards,
Fahad.